# How to pass value from visible = false textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I set a textbox visible = false on a textbox that just holds a value.  When trying to convert that value and then input it into a query it fails in visible=false.  What is the proper way to do this since this obviously is not it.  HEre is the code that passes the two textbox values to the query.

```
private void cmdAddAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            int interestsKey;
            interestsKey = Convert.ToInt32(interestsKeyTextBox.Text);
            InterestAdd newAdd = new InterestAdd();
            newAdd.CaseNumberKey = caseNumberKeyTextBox.Text;
            newAdd.InterestsKey = interestsKey;
            db.InterestAdds.InsertOnSubmit(newAdd);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            LoadCaseNumberInterestsKey(interestsKey, newAdd.CaseNumberKey, false, "interestAdd");

            this.interestAddDataGridView.EndEdit();
            this.interestAddDataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

I set the textbox behavior to visible = false.

Thanks,

Kor

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Code and the results would be useful.

Comment: In which event are you setting it?

Comment: Sure you mean winforms not ASP.NET? Because visible `false` in ASP.NET means the textbox will never reach the browser.

Comment: Show us code, or your question and our answers will be purely hypothetical.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet by fails I mean it errors out because the 2 FKs are not passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these alternatives:

- Make your textbox **enable** to **false**   (if you don't want user to modify it)
- Use a label and set its **forecolor** and **backcolor** same (which makes it invisible)

Comment: I will try the label alternative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keep your textbox visible = ture and set its height and width to ZERO.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting the visibility to false, the textbox is not included in the form element and therefore will never be posted.  If you don't care about seeing the contents of the textbox just use a hidden input.  If you want to see the contents of the textbox, but don't want it to be changed you can use the readonly attribute of the textbox and set it to true.  This will post the value back to the server with the form and not allow users to alter the value in the textbox.

Comment: what is a hidden input and how does one go about using it. Just a quick note previous to this attempt at c# my only experience is with VBA and VB from the 90s. Outside of that I am SQL Dev/ DBA so if I am not clear I apologize

Comment: This is for Winforms not ASP.Net. Edit: Scratch that, it seems the OP didn't even specify nor confirmed it one way or the other. My bet is ASP.Net also. +1

Comment: It is winforms and says so in the title and the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the Visible = false property at design time in the property sheet of the text box, or at run time in code ??

If you set the textbox Visible=false in code for e.g. in Form_Load, then it should work.

Comment: It has helped me a lot, thanks